# In JavaScript, is it possible save an on-click trigger and re-apply it later?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

On a dynamic page I wish to disable and later re-enable sections.  Visually they are grayed out, but need to prevent users from playing with the section until later.

For elements using on-click triggers, would like to:

save the current on-click trigger in an attribute

remove the current on-click trigger

add trigger that no-defaults and no-propagates

to re-enable:

get rid of the no-default trigger

re-apply the trigger previously saved

clear attribute where it was saved

From replies so far:

**conjecture:** using pure JavaScript html5 level, without delegation or some other external mechanism, it is impossible to extract the on-click trigger from an element.

---

#### Solution

was *very* tempted by delegations - and was defeated by not being able to prevent memory leaks.  ended up doing it anyway, with a simple gc to do the job.

extends (add|remove)EventListener with (add|push|pop|remove)PopableEventListener, making code change trivial.  allows me to push and pop listeners to any level - wonderful for form context changes other than merely enable/disable.

source: http://code.google.com/p/chess-spider/source/browse/http/scripts/popable.js

doc: http://code.google.com/p/chess-spider/wiki/PopableEventListener?ts=1303738300&updated=PopableEventListener

#### Editorial

Contrary to most I have seen, the ability to access listeners in the dom would be a significant benefit;  besides being able to sanely disable re-enable, the ability to coerce them into a different scope would be incredibly useful.

Comment: Depends on how you attached it in the first place. Please show some code.

Comment: Caching a function and using `removeEventListener` doesn't work?

Comment: @Felix - attached via element.addEventListener('click', func, true )

Comment: @Zirak - what do you mean by "caching a function"?

Comment: Instead of declaring an anonymous one when assigning the listener, making a named congrats. Seeing the answers, I guess that isn't the end-effect you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle hundreds of triggers is to use [event delegation](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/).

You then examine each click for if it matches your trigger. If it is the child of a disabled section you discard the click.

A jQuery implementation would be something like as follows:

```
$('.trigger', document.body).live('click', function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (target.parents('.disabled').length > 0) {
    // handle click
  }
});
```

Obviously you can use other frameworks or plain JavaScript as suits you best.

Comment: event delegation certainly has appeal - one of those thing I could easily go overboard with :}.  checking enable/disable with parents is very smart.  need to air out the delegation in my mind a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all events bubble/propagate: `change`, `focus` etc. (Actually, I mean fortunately.)

Comment: @wobleton - came up with a beautiful, non-intrusive design for delegation, but could not stop memory leaks.  this is a long-running page with a lot of dynamic components, eg, lots of dom chunks are held by javascript, swapped in and out of the document, so even if I were to do gc manually, there is no central point for me to access the universe of html elements which might be effected.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just save each onclick's enabled state into an array, then check that array each time it is called, if the state is false, just return without running anything, this could also help keep track of what to grey out.

Here is my idea: http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/MXEjv/1/
It is a bit messy, but the two top functions are the important ones.  The first will toggle (based on class), and the second will say if the element's onclick is enabled (again by class).  Just make sure the objects have the same class, and one will effect the other, and vise versa.  Alternately, you could just pass in the id, instead of using the class (like I did).
Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: @mazzzz - could do that I suppose, but have hundreds of triggers. sometimes the same trigger is called by two different elements - it may or may not be disabled according to where the elements were on the screen.  to me, it seems much more straight forward to remove and re-apply the triggers as needed - but if I can't do it, then it's not very straight forward ;)

Comment: @mazzzz - if you're suggesting that the trigger check the enabled state of the target before continuing, that might just work - it requires some cut and paste on dozens of triggers, but doable.

Comment: @cc wow, that sounds very confusing, I guess you could modify my solution to work with the sender; but that would be a pain.

Comment: And yes, that was what I was suggesting.  I'll work up an example.

Comment: Example is up, check the post.

Comment: @mazzz - ok.  you're getting close to a formal event delegation object as per @wombleton.  all three of you are talking very similar approaches.  personally like keeping into in element rather than external array, and as others have pointed out the enable/disable can be upsteam as well.

Comment: I suppose you could use a `.data('enabled',true);` if you want to keep it in-object

Comment: @mazz - imho either one needs delegation or one needs to change the triggers themselves to look for an escape condition first.  if we could store the trigger (function) in an attribute of the element this would do work (would solve memory leak problem), but can only store text.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about adding and removing listeners. You can do that a number of ways, the simplest if you only have one listener for an event is to add it as a property of the element. To remove it, just assign null:

```
function sayHi() {
  alert('hi');
}

// Add a listener
var someElement = document.getElementById('someElementID');
someElement.onclick = sayHi;

// Remove it
someElement.onclick = null;
```

If you need more than one listener for an event, you can use other schemes, such as *addEventListener* and *attachEvent*

Of course you can just track the state of the elements (say in a class or object), then the listener can respond based on the state.

Comment: the problem with your approach is re-applying the trigger:  I would need to keep track of the listener for each element.  that's why I'm trying to save that first!

Answer (score 1):

What about classes? Something like

```
function act(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    if (target.className === 'active') {
        //element active, disable it
        target.className = 'disabled';
        //other stuff
    }
    else if (target.className === 'disabled') {
        //element disabled, enable it
        target.className = 'active';
        e.preventDefault();
        //other stuff
    }
}


elem.onclick = act;
```

You can also be brave and use `data-*` attributes ([link](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/))

Comment: like keeping the info in the element, but think class is a bad idea, and, if used, should be with classList.  the data- is cool, but ff4 amazingly does not support this yet.  but nothing wrong with getAttribute.  this approach would require modification of each trigger, whereas delegation (mentioned below) _might_ shorten the width at the cost of height.